# script component

Tags: ssis

what is the use of script component in Data Flow ? Is it same as Script Task in Control flow ? Any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comparing the Script Task and the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136031.aspx)